# linking an access database to excel (without importing the whole table)

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Is there any way to link tables in an Access database to Excel without importing the entire table? I need to reference/lookup cells in the Access table but don't want to import the whole table into the excel workbook (tables are too big).

My second option is to export the Access tables into a separate excel workbook, then just reference this new workbook instead of the Access database itself. When I try to do this only around 65,000 rows of data from any Access table actually export to Excel, as the rest 'couldn't be copied to the clipboard'. Is there a simple way around this? (I want to actually have a connection between the excel/access files, so the data can be refreshed, not just copy and paste the rows over)

Comment: Yes, there's a way to connect MS Access database with Excel. See: [Connect to an Access database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-an-Access-database-a3d6500c-4bec-40ce-8cdf-fb4edb723525)

Comment: @MaciejLos When I do this, the tables I'm trying to import don't come up as options to select (I believed because they are linked tables?)

Comment: Using an excel sheet as a linked table is pretty nifty for a lot of reasons. Though I would consider data integrity and risk of getting bad data before going down this route - or having a slew of decent validations

Comment: It seems to over 65000 row after 2007.  I test 240000 row. It is possible. but needs long times.

Comment: @Ashley See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

See this ancient article, which should help you get the data you actually need rather than everything:

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/13/parameters-in-excel-external-data-queries/

Answer (score 0):

**You can work with Access database tables from Excel without importing the table into an Excel worksheet:**

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection  ' Needs a reference to the Microsoft ActiveX                         
Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset   ' Data Objects Library

Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
cnn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=database-path\Data.accdb;"
Set rs = cnn.Execute("SELECT * FROM MyTable")
While Not rs.EOF
  Debug.Print rs(1)
  rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

You may need the  [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255) which you should install with the **/passive** option if you are using a x86 Access version on a x64 OS.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following script.  This should give you what you want.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim InputFile As String
Dim InputPath As String

InputPath = "C:\your_path_here\Desktop\"
InputFile = Dir(InputPath & "*.xlsx")

Do While InputFile <> ""

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, , InputFile, InputPath & InputFile, True '< The true is for column headers
    InputFile = Dir
Loop


End Sub
```